# Replace null values in Taleo-Connect-Client extract

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

I am extracting some values from Taleo via TCC export script and few rows in a column are blank, I want to replace the blank values with 'NULL' written.

For example

SignonBonus

1.20000

2.

3.30000

4.250000

How is this possible ?

I have tried the below code, I am writing Bonus amount in words so have used concatenate function. but this replaceNull logic is not working, can someone suggest ?

---

```
<quer:projection alias="BonusinWords">
  <quer:concatenate>
    <quer:switchByCriterion>
      <quer:cases>
        <quer:case>
          <quer:replaceNull>
            <quer:field path="CurrentOffer,SignOnBonus"/>
            <quer:string>Null</quer:string>
          </quer:replaceNull>
        </quer:case>
        <quer:case>

        </quer:case>
      </quer:cases>
    </quer:switchByCriterion>
  </quer:concatenate>
</quer:projection>
```

Thanks alot in advance

Shivam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it on my own

I used a notnull equation in the starting, then wrote the below logic of query.

```
<quer:projection alias="BonusinWords">
  <quer:switchByCriterion>
    <quer:cases>
      <quer:case>
        <quer:notEqual>
          <quer:field path="CurrentOffer,SignOnBonus"/>
          <quer:string>1000000000000000000000</quer:string>
        </quer:notEqual>
        <quer:concatenate>
         <!--Between this I wrote the logic for words!>
        </quer:concatenate>
      </quer:case>
    </quer:cases>
  </quer:switchByCriterion>
</quer:projection>
```

It is not exactly not null condition, but it is serving me since the bonus amount can never be this huge(or I can add more zero's in this), if you know how not null can be put in this I will try that also.

Thanks,

Shivam

Comment: Can you include the query in your answer?

Comment: I have edited the answer, this is the logic which I used. If you have something better in mind, please let me know. Thanks